# cannot import name module with module correctly installed

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext3, aptana, windows-7-x64, python-import

new in python. 
I have python 2.7.
I just installed a new module (beatifulsoup) from cmd in windows 7 which is correctly installed : When I enter the python consol from the cmd I can import succesfully bs4 without error. 
My problem is that I cannot import it when I am using Aptana studio. Or if I code it in sublimetext and save it as a py file, when I run it I get the error message "cannot import name beautifulsoup 4". I don't get why? Is it a problem of pydev environment on aptana? If yes how can I add modules to Aptana and sublimetext3 ?

Comment: ok. problem was that I had both python 2 and 3 running and I installed BS4 on the wrong env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to import like this:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

If not, try it that way. Hope this helps!

(Perhaps you should add your import statement to the question so we can see if there is a problem with the statement or if the issue resides somewhere else)

Comment: Yes I think it was that I was following a tutorial indicating to do : from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup is now working. thanks.