# ImportError: cannot import name BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, module

In my program i used `from bs4 import BeatifulSoup`, and i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Noahs program\python black hat\retrievescreenshot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name BeatifulSoup
```

I installed bs4 from the command line with `pip.exe` from python 2.7.15.

```
pip install bs4
```

I have tried `pip install beautifulsoup4` and it said installation allready satisfied.

Comment: It says [right on their website](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) you should `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import name module with module correctly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537780/cannot-import-name-module-with-module-correctly-installed)

Comment: No I tried that...

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

then you will be able to import it

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `import`... It should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   #<-- not BeatifulSoup
```